# How do I delete an account from my monero wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli

Using monero-wallet-gui, I accidentally created an account in my wallet.  Now, I see this account in the account list whenever I use monero-wallet-gui or monero-wallet-cli.

Is it possible to delete this account?  It isn't causing me any real issues, but it is annoying to always see it in the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can't delete accounts/addresses.

That said, if it's bothering you that much, you can of course delete (move/backup first) the wallet and restore a new one from seed words, which will restore your wallet without recreating unused accounts/addresses. Be sure to backup your current wallet so you have access to things like tx private keys, labels etc which also don't get restored.

Answer (score 0):

As sample you can delete C:\Users\User\OneDrive\Documents\Monero\wallets